# How to know the duration of boot time in win XP

Tags: windows-xp, boot, time

I want to know the duration of boot time in win XP.
I tried by looking into the Event Viewer of XP but unable to find any corresponding event ID.

Thanks.

Comment: If you're just looking for the duration, and nothing else, a simple stopwatch might do the trick.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, boot-up times are not logged anywhere.  There is a application I know that does time it for you.  Its called [Soluto](https://www.soluto.com/).  Soluto will measure your boot-up time, as well as give you suggestions on how to reduce the time.

Comment: I use Soluto and it works.

Answer (score 0):

[Microsoft's BootVis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BootVis) used to work fine as well on XP (check the article for the download link, since MS no longer offers this utility).

Answer (score 0):

[Sysinternals' Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) can do boot-up logging.